# Spectral bound for maximum clique $k(G)$ in a permutation graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, sp.spectral-theory, permutations, spectral-graph-theory

Let $\pi \in S_n$ be an arbitrary permutation. By permutation graph, we refer to a simple graph with nodes $[n]$ and edges that connect pairs of nodes that appear sorted in $\pi$. Formally, $G=(V=[n],E=\{\{i,j\}\colon i<j\;\&\; \pi_i<\pi_j\})$. It is clear from the definition that an increasing subsequence in $\pi$ would correspond to a clique in $G$. As a consequence maximum clique size $k(G)$ is equal to longest increasing subsequence (LIS) in the permutation $LIS(\pi)$. If $A$ denotes the adjacency matrix of $G$ (which is symmetric and transitive), question is: What can be said about spectral properties of $A$ and $LIS(\pi)$? The general clique problem is known to be NP-hard, but there some interesting spectral bounds, for instance:
$$k(G)\ge \frac{n}{n-\lambda_1(A)}$$
derived using the theorem by Motzkin and Straus ([link](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/maxima-for-graphs-and-a-new-proof-of-a-theorem-of-turan/AC3CC45896B053B75C856F25829CA95C)).
but since we know that this specific problem has a dynamic programming solution, I am wondering if tighter bounds exist? Moroever, are there also upper bounds for $k(G)$?

This might seem like formulating an easy problem by a much harder one, but for reasons not discussed here, the spectral properties of permutation graph are of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Permutation graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_graph) are perfect, therefore [Lovasz theta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_number), which is essentially a spectral bound, computes the clique number in polynomial time in polynomial time for this class of graphs.

Comment: do you think Lovas theta function in this special case related to bound $max_{x\in S} \langle x, A x \rangle \ge \frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{k(G)})$  on the simplex: $S = \{x\in[0,1]^n\colon \sum_i x_i =1\}$ given in the Motzkin and Straus paper?

Comment: yes, these are related, as we showed in https://pure.uvt.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/844532/approxim.pdf (see Lemma 5.2) - you get a slightly different function, $\theta'$, due to A.Schrijver, but they are the same for perfect graphs, IIRC.

Comment: in case of the permutation adjacency matrix, can the SDP be approximated more efficiently than running Ellipsoid? How tight can the final value is related to the singular values of $A$? Maybe the result can be approximated by something like power iterations?

Comment: In practice noone runs the ellipsoid method (it's just the one for which the performance is understood well).